# How to set a label to mandatory in sapui5

Tags: view, label, sapui5

The final view should like this:

[image]

The code in view.xml like this:

```
    <VBox height="90px">
        <Label text="{i18n>FISCALYEAR_LABEL}" mandatory="mandatory"/>
        <Select id="FiscalYear"
            items="{
                path: '/FiscalYearSet',
                sorter: { path: 'FiscalYearID' }
              }">
            <core:Item key="{FiscalYearID}" text="{FiscalYearNum}" />
        </Select>
        <ComboBox
            items="{
                path: '/FiscalYearSet',
                sorter: { path: 'FiscalYearID' }
              }">
            <core:Item key="{FiscalYearID}" text="{FiscalYearNum}" />
        </ComboBox>
    </VBox>
```

I set a property 'mandatory="mandatory"', but it does not work.

Comment: I have known how to fix. The property is 'required="true" ' not 'mandatory="mandatory"'

Answer (score 4):

```
<Label text="{i18n>FISCALYEAR_LABEL}" required='true'/>
```

`required` is one of the properties of **sap.m.InputBase** with default `boolean` value set to `false`